# Getting the output of a running process in bash

Tags: bash, cron, server, output

So I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# IP address to cycle through (in order of priority)
ip=( "192.168.20.102" "192.168.20.103" )

# Check if synergy is already connected
if pgrep "synergyc"; then
  # Synergy already connected
  echo "Synergy is already running."
else
   for i in "${ip[@]}"
   do
     # Ping ip and connect if successful
     ping -c 1 -t 1 "$i" && /usr/bin/synergyc -n media -f "$i"
     echo "Synergy connected to ${i}";
   done
fi
```

Which gets the job done it is run as a `cron` and once an `ip` becomes available it connects. And if both are available it connects based on the order of the array.

The problem is that if it connects to an `ip` and the that `ip` becomes un-available the process just hangs with the following output.

```
[2016-08-03T22:04:53] NOTE: connecting to '192.168.20.102': 192.168.20.102:24800
[2016-08-03T22:04:53] WARNING: failed to connect to server: Connection refused
[2016-08-03T22:04:54] NOTE: connecting to '192.168.20.102': 192.168.20.102:24800
[2016-08-03T22:04:54] WARNING: failed to connect to server: Connection refused
```

What I would like to able to do is somehow capture that output check if it contains the text `WARNING` or `Connection refused` etc and `killall synergyc` based on whether or not that text exists and the presume the cron as normal.

So end goal I want `synergyc` to connect to the first available `ip` but also kill itself if the `ip` becomes un-available and resume looking for the next available `ip`.

The purpose of this script is we have a media center running at home and we use two laptops as remotes the only thing is synergy can only have one server with multiple clients not the otherway round hence the need for this script, just trying to convey that this is NOT an xy problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to run `synergyc` with `--no-restart` option. Man page says:

> --no-restart do not try to restart the client if it fails for some reason

Then if client dies for loop will continue with next ip.